# Is there a shortest code to format string

Tags: code-golf, python

## Code Golf Challenge

Given a string of 10 characters:
`'abcdefghij'`

I want to format it in this pattern and print it in the console in a minimum number of characters:
`(abc) def-ghij`

My solution:

```python
print(f"({s[0:3]}) {s[3:6]}-{s[6::]}")
```

Comment: Do you mean `(abc) def-ghijk` for output?

Comment: This might make a nice little [tag:code-golf] challenge if you open it up as such.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges! Is this intended to be a [tag:code-golf] competition? It looks like it's formatted as one, but just to be sure specifying it in the question is recommended.

Comment: I've cast the final close vote on this, but FWIW I disagree with the close reason most of the voters went with. IMO this is fine as a [tag:tips] question, it just needs some (not necessarily formal/objective) criteria to optimize for, since pretty code, short code, and fast code can be mutually exclusive and it's currently unclear which you're going for :-)

Comment: I'm so confused, I think we are in a code golf and I ask if we can do a shorter code than this one.

Maybe I was not clear on my question

Comment: @KarineBauch this is code golf *and coding challenges* :P. It wasn't clear that you asked for tips to shorten your code, if you edit the challenge to make it more explicit it can probably be reopened.

Comment: @KarineBauch You can add the [tag:code-golf] to your question to make it explicit that shortest code is your goal

Comment: Real-world best practice answer: Use https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/

Comment: Thanks I have edited the question and o-hope to be reopen

Comment: You may want to edit the title as well, as it is currently asking for "better solution" instead of "shortest code". Perhaps you should also remove `[tips]` as it is no longer relevant with your new question.

Comment: Thanks for help @doubleunary

Comment: One more clarification: do you want only Python answers, or do you want this to be a code-golf challenge open to all languages? If the former, the `[tips]` tag should be re-added and something about Python mentioned in the question body; if the latter, the `[python]` tag should be removed. Once that's done, I think this is ready to re-open.

Comment: @DLosc I want python answer :)

Comment: The `0` can be removed from your proposed solution. EDIT so can the last `:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 35 bytes

```python
print(f"({s:.3}) {s[3:6]}-{s[6:]}")
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfrGCroJSYlJySmpaekan0v6AoM69EI01Jo7rYSs@4VlOhujja2MostlYXyDCziq1V0vz/HwA)**

Uses the solution from the question but saves three bytes:

1. removes a redundant `:` in the final slice `s[6::]`, and
2. uses the `precision` specifier (`.`) of the `format_spec` (the bit after the `:` in `{...:...}`) which is overloaded for string types to give a prefix so `{s[0:3]}` -> `{s[:3]}` -> `{s:.3}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 36 bytes

*slightly improved version of your f-string (see also Jonathan Allan's comment), wrapped in a function*

```python
print(f"({s[:3]}) {s[3:6]}-{s[6:]}")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwZo025zE3KSURIViq5ilpSVpuhY3VQqKMvNKNNKUNKqLo62MY2s1FYAMYyuz2FpdIMPMKrZWSROidn2ahlJiUnJKalp6RmYWTHTBAggNAA)

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 37 bytes

*without format strings*

```python
print("("+s[:3]+")",s[3:6]+"-"+s[6:])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwZo025zE3KSURIViq5ilpSVpuhY3VQuKMvNKNJQ0lLSLo62MY7WVNJV0iqONrcyATF2QoJlVrCZE8fo0DaXEpOSU1LT0jMwsJajoggUQGgA)

uses that `print` inserts a space between arguments

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

*C-style format string*

```python
print("(%s%s%s) %s%s%s-%s%s%s%s"%(*s,))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwZo025zE3KSURIViq5ilpSVpuhY31QuKMvNKNJQ0VItBUFMBQutCKNViJVUNrWIdTU2o8kAlJaX8vFSFpMqSVIWc_Lz01CIrLoQRIO26YE3F0VbGsTrF0cZWZiDKzCpWU5MLqJmLK01DKTEpOSU1LT0jM0sJavCCBRAaAA)

printing characters separately is slightly shorter than spiting string in 3 parts

Comment: Why count function wrapper code when the question is explicitly asking for a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 46 bytes

```powershell
"($($a[0..2])) $($a[3..5])-$($a[6..9])"-join''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lDRUMlMdpAT88oVlNTAcwx1tMzjdXUBbPN9PQsYzWVdLPyM/PU1f///w8A)

The output is a little weird, if someone can suggest a fix to that it would be much appreciated!

Comment: The question seems to require Python answers.